# some .mp4 video not playing and give mime type error

Tags: video

i am using `  video control in my asp dot net site but some of the .mp4 videos are not playing and giving error mime type not found. but some .mp4 videos play. here is my code please advice

```html
   <video  controls width="100%" class="border">
                                        &nbsp; <source src='<%# Eval("video") %>' type="video/mp4">
                                        &nbsp; Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Comment: Are you sure the non-playing videos are really mp4? Use [**medaInfo**](https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo/Download) to check actual format. What does it say about video & audio codecs? Or else just provide a link to page with non-working video embedded in `video` tag...

Comment: hi, yes, the video is .mp4 format  here is the link https://globeali.com/DynamicImage/3f9934be-5457-4379-9a84-ca26c23bb206.mp4

Comment: i am using windows server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your file is a `.3gp` video just renamed to `.mp4`. 
The audio track is in `.aac` format so Chrome browser will play the sound at least (if you open file directly in new tab, but not within a `video` tag).

I suggest you re-encode a new **real** MP4 from this input file. You want MP4 that contains H264 video codec and audio as AAC for valid file that browser accepts.

For quick testing you can try converting your 3GP to MP4 with one of these sites :

- http://www.files-conversion.com/
- https://www.onlinevideoconverter.com/